# OCD Backbite thoughts

Tags: sin, forgiveness

I have these OCD thoughts if backbiting people and I do not like these thoughts I do not enjoy them because I have doubts if I’m sinning I ask Allah for forgiveness for having these thoughts of backbiting people in my mind will I be held accountable for them? And does anyone have remedies on how to get rid of these thoughts I don’t want them I try my hardest to get rid of them and I feel bad for those people who I backbited in my mind and I will make dua for them Insha’Allah

Comment: Try this dua, it's very useful. https://www.duasrevival.com/media/supplications/Protection/Dua_Protection_from_Shaytan_-_Part_1.png

Answer (score 0):

If you hate those thoughts then you don't need to be worry, as long as you hate those thoughts your iman is still there and you are not sinful for this. you should engage yourself in something like painting,reading,cooking,playing, stitching, writing, talking, listening so you can get rid of these thoughts inshallah. Whenever these thoughts come to your mind immediately start thinking about something else. Spend more time with your friends and family members. Busy yourself as much as you can because in free time there are more chances to come these thoughts in your mind.